# call to undefined function execute()

Tags: php, database, pdo

bellow is my code.Error shown is like

> fatal error: call to undefined function execute() on line 21,

how could i solve this problem?

```
<?php 

    include 'config/dbconfig.php';
    include 'lib/function.php';
    include  'helper/helper.php';

    $db = new rootfunc();
    $fm = new formate();

    if(!empty($_POST['name']) or !empty($_POST['email']) or !empty($_POST['password1']) or !empty($_POST['dob']) or !empty($_POST['gender']) ){

        $name = $fm->validation($_POST['name']);
        $email = $fm->validation($_POST['email']);
        $password = $fm->validation($_POST['password1']);
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
        $gender = $fm->validation($_POST['gender']);


        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE name = ? AND email = ?");
        $query = execute(array($name,$email));
        $numRow = $query->rowCount();

        if(!$numRow){

            $query = "INSERT INTO user_table (name,email,password,dob,gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

            $query = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $query->execute(array($name,$email,$password,$dob,$gender));
            echo "Congrates, please login..";

        }else{

            echo "name and email exist..";

        }



    }


?>
```

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: ok,but what's the problem on execute pdo method in line number 21.

Comment: The problem is basically that you forgot to use the PDO object and just called `execute()` which, yes you guessed it **is an undefined function** i.e. it does not exist in base PHP

Comment: thanks u pick the right thing......problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you are overwriting `$query`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_table (name,email,password,dob,gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$query = $pdo->prepare($query);
```

You need to give the execution a *different* variable to hold the object, for example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_table (name,email,password,dob,gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->execute(array($name,$email,$password,$dob,$gender));
```

---

In addition you should allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire. [Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

While you're working with passwords never store them as plain text! Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

---

I also noticed this in your code

```
$numRow = $query->rowCount();
```

Since the query is a `SELECT` query it will not work with rowCount()

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

For `SELECT` when you are not doing a `COUNT()` query you can return the number of rows like this after you execute the query;

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);
```

In your case it is not necessary to check the count though - just check to make sure the query executed which is enough to get into your conditional statements.

Comment: problem not solved                                                                      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE name = ? AND email = ?");
  $result = execute(array($name,$email));
  $numRow = $result->rowCount();

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. That doesn't tell me how the problem was not solved.